# RB Tree insertion scenario

Tags: data-structures, red-black-tree

I was looking at **Fig 5** of example insertions in [this red-black tree tutorial](http://lcm.csa.iisc.ernet.in/dsa/node116.html):

[image]

I think even before inserting the new node with key `x`, the tree is already violating the rule which says:

> All the external nodes black height should be same.

In my view, the black height of external nodes at node `15` is one more than the black height of external nodes at node `8`.

I found that this use case is explained in all text books and online resources, so I am confused here.

How was the tree actually a RB tree before inserting the new node?

Comment: I don't think those figures are showing the "complete" tree, just a sub-tree which needs to be fixed by a number of rotations. I think what's important is the initial state (before x is inserted) is restored after all rotations are complete.

Comment: @Justin - We can consider it as a complete tree. Before inserting the node x, It was supposed to be a RB tree. Before inserting x, 8 was not having any right child. So its null right child was having a black height of 1. null left/right children of 15 are having black height 2.  So its a violation of RB tree rule. My point here is tree  does not conform to rb tree rules even before inserting x.

Comment: @Rejeev My point was, they aren't showing the whole balanced tree; just the significant parts needed to perform the required actions.